# cache 1 file for multi domains

Tags: php, caching, cache-control

First of all, I'm sorry about the title. I couldn't find a better one.

I've a image file, generated by a PHP script. this script (image) is connected to a database and saves its referrer url in a table.
Because the output image doesn't change, I think it's better to cache it.

But as I know, if I cache 1 file (for example http://www.example.com/img.png.php), on every pages, the browsers reads it from cache. and it's not good for my script. because on the first call, it save the referrer url and cached by browser. And on the next calls, on different websites (referrers), cached version will be used and browser don't send any request to the server, and finally referrer url won't save in the database.

Can I say to browser, please cache 1 copy of the image for each domain?
I mean:

> `http://wwww.abc.com/index.html` sends a request to get my image (script)
>
> browser checks its cache, and doesn't find it. so get it from the
>   server. and PHP script saves the referrer url.
>
> the user goes to another page of ABC.COM. (for example: `http://wwww.abc.com/about.html`) browser check the cache, it finds
>   it. so doesn't send a request to the server to get the file content.
>   and PHP script won't run.
>
> another site (`http://wwww.efg.com/index.html`) sends a request to get my image (script)
>   browser checks cache, and WILL NOT find it. so send a request for file
>   content. and PHP script runs...............................

Is it possible?
(sorry for long text, with a lots of grammatical problems)

Comment: HTTP referer is entirely unreliable anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a redirect page (that is not cached) that saves the referrer to your database and then redirects to the cached image.

That way you always get a hit but the actual image is cached.

---

In your HTML you could use:

```
<img src="/image.php">
```

And in `image.php`:

```
<?php
    // save the referrer in here

    header('Location: /image.jpg');
?>
```

and `/image.jpg` is your actual image (which can be cached)

Comment: I can't understand. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think about the user's experience: Do you really need to increase page load time just for the referrer feature? Also, you should be aware that many browser/privacy tool configurations suppress or don't send the `Referer` header in the first place.

If you're really sure that you want the resource(JavaScript, stylesheet, image, ...) to load each time, you can send the [`Cache-Control` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) with the resource to prevent caching. For example, to prevent caching of `referer.js` when served with Apache, add the following `.htaccess` file in the same directory (requires [`mod_header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header)):

```
<FilesMatch "^referer\.js$">
Header set Cache-Control no-cache
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Because I think about users, I want to cache it. I mean can browser cache same file twice for 2 different websites (referrer)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a counter, am I right?

AFAIK you cannot do exactly what you've explained.

But you always can "cache" an image on the server side so you wouldn't need to redraw it:

```
<?
/*
  do some stuff
*/
// send an image: the content-type first
header('Content-type: image/png');
// and the image
readfile('myImage.png');
```

Comment: Image was an example. It can be a script, style sheet, etc.